# Javascript, I can't with the sun to reach the above items to a iframe

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, popup

I have to create the effect of a popup using a DIV with DOM, I used an iframe, inside the frame is a form, I can not get rid of the div with Javascript in the submit button because the DOM sees only after the iframe his creation and not the div that contains it ... how should I do?

```
<html> 
  <body >
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </body>
 </html>
```

---

//Global variable which contain reference to divPopup's element

```
var divPopup;
function hideDiv() {   
  window.alert("Content of DIV POPUP " + divPopup );  
  divPopup.className = "overlayHidden";
}


function load_page() {

    var nodoDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    divPopup = nodoDiv;
    nodoDiv.className = "overlay";
    nodoDiv.setAttribute("id", "popup1");
    //nodoDiv.addEventListener("click", function () { hideDiv(); }, false);

    document.body.appendChild( nodoDiv );

    var nodoDivPopup = document.createElement("DIV");
    nodoDivPopup.setAttribute("id", "popup2");
    nodoDivPopup.className = "popup";
    var elem = document.getElementById("popup1");
    divPopup = elem;
    elem.appendChild( nodoDivPopup );

    var nodoDivEsami= document.createElement("DIV");
    nodoDivEsami.setAttribute("id", "contenitoreEsami");
    nodoDivEsami.className = "content";
    var elem = document.getElementById("popup2");
    elem.appendChild( nodoDivEsami );

    var nodoIFrame = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    nodoIFrame.className = "content";
    nodoIFrame.setAttribute("src", "esami_da_importare_TEST.html");
    var nodoDivEsami = document.getElementById("contenitoreEsami");
    nodoDivEsami.appendChild( nodoIFrame );
    //window.alert( document.body.innerHTML ); 

}
```

_______file css

```
.overlayHidden{
  visibility:hidden;
   opacity:0;
  }
```

the function `hideDiv()` is in the form, activated `onClick` on submit button.
the `window.alert( )` in function `hideDiv` return "undefined"...

Comment: Why did you use an iframe? It seems unrelated to the popover. You could try using window.top to refer to the parent document from inside the iframe document.

Comment: > "I can't with the sun" ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying too hard, as iFrames are notoriously problematic. You don't need to use an iFrame, and you can predefine your DIVs in the HTML (unless you really need to create the DIV dynamically). For example:

```
<div id="popup1" class="overlayHidden">
   <div id="contenitoreEsami" class-"content">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

No code is needed for page load. When you want to display the pop-up, change its class to something that isn't hidden.

Comment: yes, i need to create a DIV dynamically for Project Specifications.
however, I found the problem: use document.parent.document.getElementById("popup1");